# Java - Convert JSON to XML with values on root tag

Tags: java, json, xml, converters

I need to convert JSON to XML format with values in the root tag

I have and **Orden class** configured with `@JsonRootName("orden")` and added `@JsonProperty` to all properties.

Actually, I have an implementation that converts JSON to XML but with "values in child nodes".

This is my converter implementation:

```java
public static String convertJsonObjectToXml (Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        String xml = XML.toString(json);
        return xml;
    }
```

The result of that implementation is this:

```xml
<orden>
                <formaOp>C</formaOp>
                <agente>109</agente>
                <tipo>C</tipo>
                <precio>2.5</precio>
                <tipoVenc>72</tipoVenc>
                <idOrigen>156934</idOrigen>
                <instrumento>TS</instrumento>
                <ejecucion>SINCRONICA</ejecucion>
                <agenteCtpte>3</agenteCtpte>
                <comitente>0</comitente>
                <fechaOrigen>2013-10-09T08:04:13</fechaOrigen>
                <cantidad>10</cantidad>
</orden>
```

But I need the shorter, unfriendly or whatever formats name of the XML below

```xml
<orden idOrigen="156934" fechaOrigen="2014-02-19T15:11:44.000-03:00" 
        agente="109" agenteCtpte="3" tipo="C" ejecucion="SINCRONICA" instrumento="TS" 
    cantidad="10" precio="2.5" formaOp="C" tipoVenc="72"/>
```

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using two different JSON libraries? --- Anyway, since you're using Jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert to JSON, why not use JAXB to convert the object to XML? That way you have full control of the XML generation using JAXB annotations.

Comment: Thaks! I'll put an answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment posted by Andreas, I used JAXB and my **Orden** class now is hybrid (can be converted from JSON or XML).

This is how the object is configured:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class IngresarOrden extends DatosOferta {

    private String accion;

    private ModoEjecucion ejecucion;

    private String operador;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getAccion() {
        return accion;
    }
    public void setAccion(String accion) {
        this.accion = accion;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public ModoEjecucion getEjecucion() {
        return ejecucion;
    }
    public void setEjecucion(ModoEjecucion ejecucion) {
        this.ejecucion = ejecucion;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getOperador() {
        return operador;
    }
    public void setOperador(String operador) {
        this.operador = operador;
    }
```

The `@XmlAttribute` is the annotation needed to put the values in the root tag.

This is the full converter implementation:

```
public static <T> String converToXml (T obj) throws CommonsException {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        String xml = null;
        try {
            OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, os);
            xml = os.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error("XML converter exception: ", e);
            throw new CommonsException("XML converter exception: ", e);
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

Thanks!